osTicket update column for each activity performed on a ticket
We have an ongoing osTicket activity and we are introducing the ability to transfer a ticket from one department to another in our team. While testing the process, we noticed that the "Last update" column doesn't trigger for transfers or internal notes. Unfortunately this is a problem because in this case our agents can't see the new updated ticket when we transfer it to them.
I checked the osTicket forum and some threads on github and it seems that this column only updates on some specific activity on the ticket.
We were trying to see if there was a way to have another column that could show us the last time a ticket had any updates,from messages, internal notes and transfer, or some other way to show our agents a newly transfered ticket. We noticed that in the database we have two different columns of the ost_ticket table, "lastupdate" and "updated", where the last one is in fact updated on any action taken.
Is there a way to create one column from this? We have consulted some forums and we have seen the community asking for this functionality as "Last activity" column, but we don't have any information on its implementation. Do you have any suggestions to solve this problem?ost_ticket table's columns mentioned
